# How to create slideshow like mentioned link on my web page?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am very new to programming. I want to put slideshow on my webpage like on [Unify](http://htmlstream.com/unify/)

I am aware of creating simple slideshow using bootstrap carousel. But not getting idea to get slideshow like mentioned link. How its done, What i need to learn for it and any other inputs will be useful.

Comment: read up on [parallax scrolling](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/) and combine that with your basic bootstrap carousel, you've got something which almost looks like what you need

Comment: Oh, and look up on [CSS3 transitions](http://www.css3.info/preview/css3-transitions/) as well.

Comment: The site you mentioned uses [Parallax Slider](http://www.parallaxslider.com/), but that is a premium plugin and you can instead have a look at [Sequence Slider](http://www.sequencejs.com/) which has the same features and free too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [working Bootstrap Carousel example](http://www.bootply.com/63634) that uses jQuery `.animate()` to create a similar effect. The demo also uses the `carousel-pills` (added after Bootstrap 2.3.x) for the dot navigation on the bottom of each slide. This does not include all of the elements of the Unify page slider, but will give you an understanding of how this could be achieved using the Bootstrap Carousel without an extra plugin..

<kbd>[**Demo on Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/63634)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Its immensly helpful